# Angular2 rc3 Angularfire3 cant find Promise

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am trying to use Angularfire2 with the Angular2 starter, but I get the following error:

```
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase3.d.ts(33,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
```

I tried this: typings install dt~es6-promise --global --save 
But I still get: `node_modules/angularfire2/firebase3.d.ts(33,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.`

This is what I did:

1)Clone the angular2 starter

2)npm install

3)npm install angularfire2 firebase --save

4)typings install dt~es6-promise --global --save

5)Add "files": [ "node_modules/angularfire2/firebase3.d.ts" ] to tsconfig.json

I also added es-6 promise via npm install es-6promise, no luck. 
When I change the target to es6, the code is not translated to js anymore, but the error is gone. 
I would be very happy if anyone could point my in the right direction.